# Running a windows executable within R using wine in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, wine

I am trying to execute a windows only executable called (groundfilter.exe from FUSION) within Rstudio on Ubuntu. 
I am able to run groundfilter.exe from a terminal using wine as follows:

```
wine C:/FUSION/groundfilter.exe /gparam:0 /wparam:1 /tolerance:1    /iterations:10 test_Grnd.las 1 test.las
```

The executes fine and produces file test_Grnd.las OK.
But when i try to do this from within Rstudio using system() it doesn't quite work, and no output file is produced (unlike from terminal). I do this:

```
command<-paste("wine C:/FUSION/groundfilter.exe",
           "/gparam:0 /wparam:1 /tolerance:1 /iterations:10",
           "/home/martin/Documents/AUAV_Projects/test_FUSION/test_FUSION/test_GroundPts.las", 
           "1", 
           "/home/martin/Documents/AUAV_Projects/test_FUSION/test_FUSION/test.las",sep=" ")
system(command)
```

The executable appears to be called OK in Rstudio console, but run as if no file names were supplied. The output( truncated ) is:

```
system(command)
GroundFilter v1.75 (FUSION v3.60) (Built on Oct  6 2016 08:45:14) DEBUG
--Robert J. McGaughey--USDA Forest Service--Pacific Northwest Research    Station
Filters a point cloud to identify bare-earth points

Syntax: GroundFilter [switches] outputfile cellsize datafile1 datafile2   ...
outputfile   Name for the output point data file (stored in LDA format)
```

This is the same output from the terminal if the file names are left off, so  somehow my system call in R is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think wine will not find paths like /home/martin/....

One possibility would be to put groundfilter.exe (and possibly dlls it needs) into the directory you want to work with, and set the R working directory to that directory using setwd().

The other possibility I see would be to give a path that wine understands, like `Z:/home/martin/...`.

This is not an authoritative answer, just my thoughts, so please refer to the documentation for the real story.